# Javascript OnClick function for multiple Div Class elements that reveal a block of text when clicked on

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to enable an Onclick event to fire up when any of my div elements that match the div class "Clicker"  is clicked on.
However iI am not so good with JavaScript and do not know how to go about this.
I was successful when I used the "document.getElementById" when my divs were made into Id and not "Class" elements but only one could function.
see my code below;

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("Clicker").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var infoBox = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail-reveal-txt");



  if (infoBox.style.display == "none") {
    infoBox.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    infoBox.style.display = "none";
  }


})
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-reveal-txt" style="position: absolute; display: none;">
<div class="thumbnail-reveal-txt" style="position: absolute; display: none;">
<div class="thumbnail-reveal-txt" style="position: absolute; display: none;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`

```js
document.querySelector(".Clicker").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const infoBox = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail-reveal-txt");
  infoBox.forEach(i => {
    if (i.style.display == "none") {
      i.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        i.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="Clicker">click</button>
<div class="thumbnail-reveal-txt" style="position: absolute; display: none;">1</div>
<div class="thumbnail-reveal-txt" style="position: absolute; display: none;">2</div>
<div class="thumbnail-reveal-txt" style="position: absolute; display: none;">3</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input.
while this may have seemed to somewhat work, i now have 2 new issues.
Firstly, when i fire ONLY the top most div/button, ALL the other elements display at the same time! and all close also at the same time.

Secondly, I cant get the other divs/buttons to produce the same result that the first one is producing, i.e, they are not displaying or hiding the hidden div.
Please advise what could be wrong.

Comment: Pls share some more code and explain what you want to achieve, so i can try to help you, cheers

Comment: Hi Nikola,
This is my scenario.
I have 3 divs, each div has a block of hidden text in it which should appear only when i click the button for it to show, hence my HTML mark up snippet.
So what i would like is that the information only shows in the current div i have activated it in, and not all 3 at once. 
See more html, the CSS has been left out to reduce on code.

Comment: <div class="thumbnail-tiles>
 <div class="tile-header front">
  <h3>FFront of Tile</h3>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail-reveal-txt" style="position: absolute; display: none;"> /**The text to be activated only after click**/
  /*some text here*/

</div>
<div id="learn-more">
 <h3 class="Clicker">Click for More</h3>/**This should display the hidden text when clicked**/
</div>

Answer (score 0):

When you use getElementsByClassName, you're not specifying wich of the elements you are trying to change the className property.

For that, you can use a loop

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Clicker").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var infoBox = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail-reveal-txt");

for (let i = 0; i < infoBox.length; i +=1) {

if (infoBox[i].style.display == "none") {
    infoBox[i].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    infoBox[i].style.display = "none";
  }

}
 


})
```